# Can't import: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm following my teachers tutorial and therefore writing exactly the same code that he has in his example. So I just created a new class to learn `RecyclerView` but I can't import `RecyclerView` On mouse-over, it just says "**Cannot resolve symbol RecyclerView**". I use `Android Studio 2.3.3.` Am I missing something obvious?

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComposedAdapter.Holder> {
//stuff 
}
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "sofialarsson.customrecyclerview"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Try this compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

Comment: did you add `compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7` inside your gradle

Comment: @akhilesh0707 when I add that line in gradle it expects some numbers(??) after "-v7"?

Comment: after the v7: you need to specify the version check below Nilesh answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add dependencies in `build.gradle`

Use this update `gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "sofialarsson.customrecyclerview"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0"

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: why two com.android.support:appcompat-v7 dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using androidx artifacts, add the following to your app level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the import is now `import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Answer (score 5):

Might be useful, so Let me drop this for those who might want to migrate to androidx. In your build.gradle (Module app) add the dependency like this, instead of:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Then import like this, instead of:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

use:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Sync and enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Add below dependency in build.gradle;

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:xx.x.x'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add these two dependencies and you are good to go.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Make sure always always use same versions everywhere like you use here 25.3.1.
Also update your `buildToolsVersion="25.0.0"`  .
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` dependencies in  `build.gradle` app file like below code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency in build.gradle

> implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta02'

[Link Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) for latest releases

Answer (score 0):

to give you an up-to-date and comprehensive answer, you have two choices.

**Pre Android 9.0 (pre API 28)**, you have to use the old Support Library:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0"
}
```

For these dependencies, you have to use the version number of your Build Tools Version.

**In Android 9.0 (API 28+) and above**, you have to use the new Support Library (Noted here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features#v7):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
}
```

For these dependencies, you have to use the version numbers from the following pages:

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Add this class in the main_activity.xml file:

```
class="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"/>
```

Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView
for more info...